# How can I make Tcl/Tk buttons behave like radiobuttons?

Tags: button, radio-button, tcl, tk-toolkit

**According to the ActiveTcl 8.5 Documentation:**
ttk::radiobutton widgets are used in groups to show or change a set of mutually-exclusive options. Radiobuttons are linked to a Tcl variable, and have an associated value; when a radiobutton is clicked, it sets the variable to its associated value.
**And a more general definition:**
You use radio buttons for mutually exclusive settings. Clicking on one causes any other that has been pressed to pop up, just like on an old car radio.

I really prefer to use the look and feel of buttons instead of radio buttons. How can I achieve the same behaviour of radiobuttons in a group of buttons?
I found on http://wiki.tcl.tk/17899 about toggle buttons, but these behaves more like checkbuttons.

Any insights really appreacited. Thank you

Comment: I am wandering if I can use a label instead of button to act as a radiobutton.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the button's `relief` to maintain it's sunken-ness.

```
set colours {red blue green}
foreach c $colours {
    pack [button .$c -text $c -command [list pushed $c]]
}

proc pushed colour {
    puts $colour
    set label [.$colour cget -text]
    foreach c $::colours {
        .$c configure -relief [expr {$c eq $label ? "sunken" : "raised"}]
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, is working great. I managed to modify your script to be use with labels as well by adding the following line:bind .$c <ButtonPress-1> "pushed $c"

Answer (score 1):

Set the radiobuttons' [-indicatoron](http://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TkCmd/radiobutton.htm#M8) attribute to false.